# Return query results on single lines

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to list out the versions of .Net installed on our systems and, for some reason, my query is returning the results in a separate row for the 4.0 versions. Here's my query;

```
SELECT sys1.Netbios_NSELECT sys1.Netbios_Name0 AS Computername
    ,Max(CASE dn.Version0
            WHEN '1.0'
                THEN CASE dn.BuildNumber0
                        WHEN IsNull(dn.BuildNumber0, 1)
                            THEN dn.BuildNumber0
                        END
            END) AS [.Net 1.0]
    ,Max(CASE dn.Version0
            WHEN '1.1'
                THEN CASE dn.BuildNumber0
                        WHEN IsNull(dn.BuildNumber0, 1)
                            THEN dn.BuildNumber0
                        END
            END) AS [.Net 1.1]
    ,Max(CASE dn.Version0
            WHEN '2.0'
                THEN CASE dn.BuildNumber0
                        WHEN IsNull(dn.BuildNumber0, 1)
                            THEN dn.BuildNumber0
                        END
            END) AS [.Net 2.0]
    ,Max(CASE dn.Version0
            WHEN '3.0'
                THEN CASE dn.BuildNumber0
                        WHEN IsNull(dn.BuildNumber0, 1)
                            THEN dn.BuildNumber0
                        END
            END) AS [.Net 3.0]
    ,Max(CASE dn.Version0
            WHEN '3.5'
                THEN CASE dn.BuildNumber0
                        WHEN IsNull(dn.BuildNumber0, 1)
                            THEN dn.BuildNumber0
                        END
            END) AS [.Net 3.5]
    ,Max(CASE dn.Version0
            WHEN '3.5'
                THEN CASE dn.ServicePack0
                        WHEN IsNull(dn.ServicePack0, 1)
                            THEN dn.ServicePack0
                        END
            END) AS [.Net 3.5 ServicePack]
    ,Max(CASE dn.Version0
            WHEN '4.0'
                THEN CASE dn.BuildNumber0
                        WHEN IsNull(dn.BuildNumber0, 1)
                            THEN dn.BuildNumber0
                        END
            END) AS [.Net 4.0]
    ,Max(CASE dn.Version0
            WHEN '4.0'
                THEN CASE dn.Release0
                        WHEN IsNull(dn.Release0, 1)
                            THEN dn.Release0
                        END
            END) AS [.Net 4.0 Release]
    ,ConfigurationManager_002.dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM.Domain0 AS Domain
    ,sys1.Operating_System_Name_and0 AS Operating_System
    ,ConfigurationManager_002.dbo.v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS.LastHWScan
FROM v_r_system_valid sys1
LEFT JOIN v_gs_dotnetframeworks0 dn ON dn.ResourceID = sys1.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN ConfigurationManager_002.dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM ON sys1.ResourceID = ConfigurationManager_002.dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM.ResourceID
LEFT JOIN ConfigurationManager_002.dbo.v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS ON ConfigurationManager_002.dbo.v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS.ResourceID = sys1.ResourceID
GROUP BY sys1.Netbios_Name0
    ,dn.Release0
    ,ConfigurationManager_002.dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM.Domain0
    ,sys1.Operating_System_Name_and0
    ,ConfigurationManager_002.dbo.v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS.LastHWScan
ORDER BY ComputerName
```

and my results appear as such;

Query results

[image]

Comment: You group by 5 columns, you display only 4 of those. Generally, this is a logical flaw in queries like this. Either add the missing column to the select list or remove it from the group by clause. And for your own good and the sanity of others, give a reasonably short alias to each table / view and use it when referencing columns.

Comment: Ha! Great catch!! I removed the dn.Release0 column from the group by clause and the results are clean now. Absolutely amazed how fast you can spot that.

Comment: 3+ naming for columns is also deprecated; you're using 4 part naming for them. Aliases would hugely make the above more succinct and readable.